# Using mandrill as a mail transport layer in Zend 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, mandrill

Currently, I am trying to integrate Mandrill functionality into a Zend 1 legacy application, and I'm not too familiar with the way they handle mail transports. Currently, I'm including the `mandrill/mandrill` composer package and attempting to follow the pattern of the other transport layers included in Zend 1:

```
class MandrillTransport extends Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract
{
    private $message = array();

    protected function _formatMandrillArray() 
    {
        //grab all the relavant data from the pre-existing mail object and put it into a Mandrill-friendly array
    }
    protected function _getAttachments() {
        //loop through and format attachments that get added to array
    }
    protected function _sendMail()
    {
       //send Mandrill message with included data
       $mandrill = new Mandrill(Zend::registry('config')->mandrill->APIKey);
       $mandrill->messages->send($this->message);
    }
    public function send() {
      //Format all the stuff and send it
    }
}
```

And then I'm assuming I can use this in the "send()" function, which appears to take the transport as a parameter:

```
            //TODO: Put this in a better spot
        require_once __DIR__ . "/ZendFramework/Zend/Mail/Transport/MandrillTransport.php";
        $tr = new MandrillTransport();
        $email->send($tr);
```

Am I on the right track here? The reason I'd like to do this as a transport layer rather than just ripping out the existing code and replacing it with Mandrill is because there are a lot of different business processes sending mail, and we'd like to be able to pick and choose which is using the Sendmail transport and which are using Mandrill.

Thanks in advance,
-Chris

Comment: Have you determined whether you're on the right track or not on this? I'm considering doing the same thing.